# Merge request for the answers from 2 duplicate questions

Tags: support, merge, duplicates

The question [How to find which file is under heavy use/IO](https://serverfault.com/questions/543457/how-to-find-which-file-is-under-heavy-use-io) was rightfully marked as a duplicate of [Linux IO monitoring per file](https://serverfault.com/questions/327985/linux-io-monitoring-per-file) and it was closed, but its answers weren't moved to the "original" question. I'd like them to be moved, so that they don't get lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those answers could use a touch of cleanup... But they're merged now.

Also, closed questions with upvoted answers are never removed or otherwise "lost".

Comment: Unless they are voted into deletion, at which point they are as good as lost.

Comment: Ok... Incredibly unlikely, but possible. All the authors could still see their own work though, and a simple flag to a mod could remedy even that most unlikely of situations.